# HTML form handling with PHP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to set a simple form handling with HTML and PHP, but all my attempts have failed. I tried searching it up, but nothing worked. This is my HTML code right now, and I just want it to display the name and email, and also later learn how to transfer the data to JavaScript for easier manipulation. I already know how to execute a JS function in HTML, I'm just wondering syntax for transferring, or if you even have to do it with PHP. My HTML code is the path: /Users/Splavacado100/Desktop/SNW/home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That seems fine, but are you running this on a webserver with PHP, and how are you catching the form on the server

Comment: I believe the: action="/action_page.php" transfers the data. Ultimately, I would like the form data to become variables in my javascript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="hidden" value="submitted" />
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

action_page.php

```
<?php

    $DataReceived = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['submitted'] ) ) ? $_REQUEST['submitted'] : '';

    if( !empty( $DataReceived ) )
    {

        $name   = trim($_REQUEST['name']);
        $email  = trim($_REQUEST['email']);

        //You can now save this into database or use data to validate user or transactions

        echo "Name is :  $name";
        echo "<br>Email is : $email";
    }

?>
```

#### JavaScript | jQuery Form Submission to PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form id="dataForm" action="action_page.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="hidden" value="submitted" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#submit').bind('click', processData);

            });

            function processData(){
                var datas = $("#dataForm").serializeArray();

                $.post('action_page.php', datas, function(data, status){
                    $('#results').html(data); // if you want to see the status from php file.. live result.
                });

            }

        </script>       
        <div id="results" style="width:100%"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### To learn more about php visit [PHP Website](http://php.net?r=lvc)

### Happy Coding

Comment: The PHP doesn't execute, it just displays the code.

Comment: PHP file cannot just php display the code unless `php` is not enabled .  To enable `php` do: `a2enmod php5` and then restart your apache server.  you can save this `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into a ***test.php*** and access it from a browser to see if it works.